# Error Retrieving Data from React Redux Store and Mapping to Props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React component which is fetching data via API to retrieve an product Object by using the ID passed in as a prop to the component.

I have a React / Redux app and I am fairly new to Redux flow.
I have the Products (array with one Product object) data loading via my Action / Reducer to the store.

I am trying to pass this from state to props using the mapStateToProps pattern.

I am getting the following error when it is rendering the `{ this.props.product.title }`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$z9gkwvwuolc' of null
```

I think its due to it being data thats asynchronous.
What's the best way to solve for this?

Below is my code --

```
class ProductListItem extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchProduct(this.props.id));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{ this.props.product.title }</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Actions required to provide data for this component to render in sever side.
ProductListItem.need = [() => { return fetchProduct(this.props.id); }];

// Retrieve data from store as props
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    product: state.products.data[0],
  };
}

ProductListItem.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  overlay: PropTypes.string,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductListItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the product exist, you will access the inner data only if it exist. This a common pattern:

```
class ProductListItem extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchProduct(this.props.id));
  }

  render() {
    const { product } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        { product &&
          <h1>{product.title}</h1>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If the product exist, then the component will render the `<h1>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your redux reducer you can define the default state, set the default state and then you can do some ternary checking

```
export default function reducer(state={ title : undefined}, action) {

//ternary checking in render() on component
product.title !== undefined ? product.title : undefined
```

This means, if product.title isn't undefined, then render product.title else undefined.